# How to improve OpsWorks node's boot time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, boot, aws-opsworks

I like AWS OpsWorks but one big drawback I am facing now is boot time: nodes are booting super slowly.

In my case, for a t1.micro instance, it takes like 10 minutes before my cookbook can start running (although from EC2 console view, the instance should be ready after about 2 minutes: it can be accessed via SSH after this short period). You can also refer to [this topic](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=478248).

I tried using custom AMI but ran into another problem: the node kept booting forever. But that might be my fault while creating the AMI.

Back to the original question, how can I improve this boot time of OpsWorks nodes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case, using m1.small, I followed [this doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-custom-ami.html) to create a custom AMI.

I think the reason it kept booting forever is the opsworks-agent files are still there. See step 4 under **To create a custom AMI from an AWS OpsWorks instance**, you'd need to stop agent and delete it's files.

The complete cycle improved from ~25 minutes down to ~10 minutes. By the ~11th minute, it's on LB health checks stage.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice to have clue on why the instance hangs forever. I will try your solution and get back with the result. Thank you!

Comment: Amazing! It works like a charm. It saves me 6 minutes on a t1.micro instance. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

(Can't comment. Need 50pts) I don't get it. If you remove the agent, what is the point of using OpsWorks? The agent allows you to update the instance and add recipes as needed. Not to mention add instances based on predefined configurations. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am not sure. This is for creating new AMI, so I guess OpsWorks wants a pure AMI and will install new agent on that instance in some way when it is launched. Regards.

Comment: Opsworks is still useful for creating and setting up the machine to create the AMI from.  If you need to update the AMI, its better to be able to update your Opsworks configuration and recipes and create a new instance from scratch then just manually updating your AMI manually.

Answer (score 0):

Although is not clearly specified on this thread it looks like you were creating the custom AMI from either the Amazon linux or the Ubuntu instances that are already offered.
In my case (being the reason why I ended up here), I created the custom AMI directly from a regular EC2 instance and still, after almost 14 hours the instance would not start. I made sure I removed any other configuration that could be blocking us like, ELB/VLC configurations and custom recipes. The instance is basically stuck on the setup stage.

One of the possible reasons why it would get stuck on booting is because a custom AMI that is created from an image that has an Opworks agent that should be linked to that image only. Look at the documentation here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-custom-ami.html
But that is not my case.

I will try with a predefined Amazon image and go from there.

Comment: Update: I was able to get the Amazon Linux 12.9 instance to go from booting to running setup. It only took the time it took me to write the original post above. Is it possible we have to delete agents from regular EC2 Ami's as well? That wouldn't make sense but who knows, perhaps is something else blocking custom AMI's from booting. And btw, my original Custom AMI instance was from RHEL 6.5 32 bit on a t1.micro instance. There was NOTHING fancy installed in it.

Comment: Hi einarc. As mrclmrvn pointed out in his answer, you'd need to stop agent and delete it's files.

Comment: @TungNguyen Hi Tung. I know, I put that on my very first comment but it got deleted by an admin. See here for more details on the problem I'm having. While default AMI's work fine I can't get it to work with Custom AMI's from EC2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005004/aws-opworks-instances-not-starting-when-created-from-custom-ami-on-ec2

Answer (score 0):

If your instance will not start check my answer here:

[AWS Opworks Instances not starting when created from Custom AMI on EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005004/aws-opworks-instances-not-starting-when-created-from-custom-ami-on-ec2/28766015#28766015)

maybe will solve your problem...